# Get response from ajax post form call when using data which is displayed using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown box, and when it changed, i will display a table containing information in the database using JQuery. Now that one is working good. In the same time, I want to apply the "edit in place" to that table. When I clicked a row, then I am able to change the value of the row,however, the data is not change when I submit the new value. I have to refresh my page and then the value will be updated. I suspect it is because of the table which is called using JQuery. But here is the codes.  I am using this function to display the table of information:

```
function loadData(page){
    var dataString = "";
    dataString = "page="+page;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_data.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(msg){
            $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {
                $("#container").html(msg);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I am using this code to apply "edit in place" which is currently working, but the only thing which is not working is when I want to reload the table with the new value.

```
$(".edit_tr").live('click',function(){
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');

    $("#first_"+ID).hide();
    $("#first_input_"+ID).show();
    var first=$("#first_input_"+ID).val();

}).live('change', function(){
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    var first=$("#first_input_"+ID).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&thename='+first;

    var initName = $("#hidden_first_input_"+ID).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "edit_page.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
              alert(html); // the alert is not coming. even put any process, nothing happen
        }
     });
});
```

But the values is updating into the database. I have to refresh, and call the table one more time using JQuery then the value will be updated. Or I can click the paging, then it will be correct. ANy idea why is this happening? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Whats the edit_page.php supposed response to the post?

Comment: just a new value updated to database...